# ProgressDialog onClickListener

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener

i have a list in my Android APP and i need to show a progress dialog when the user click on an item.

I use this code for starting the activity. I tried to put a progressdialog and always fail...

Pasted the code and please tell me your opinion.

```
    public OnClickListener myClickListener = new OnClickListener() {        

    public void onClick(View v) {   


        String param1 = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtdat1))
                .getText().toString();
        String param2 = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtdat2))
                .getText().toString();
        String param3 = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtdat3))
                .getText().toString();
        String param4 = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtdat14))
                .getText().toString();

        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), AgendaDetail.class);

        intent.putExtra("param1", param1);
        intent.putExtra("param2", param2);
        intent.putExtra("param3", param3);
        intent.putExtra("param4", param4);

        startActivity(intent);

    }
};
```

Y try tu put something similar to that

```
        final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading...",
            "Wait");
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            startActivity(new Intent("com.places"));
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: You don't have any code related to a ProgressDialog in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need to write this on the onclick**

```
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(YourActivity.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Your message"));
    progressDialog.show();
```

This will help...

Comment: The problem is to put this inside the onClickListener

Comment: so are you not able to do that?? what problem are you facing can i know?

Comment: The constructor ProgressDialog(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined

Comment: activity switching is done very quickly, there is no need to show the progressDialog for it.. Is that really a requirement for you..??

Comment: Thx for solution. My problem was in YouActivity.this.... my main forgot to read this part !! :D Thx for support